# Excel Office 365 Cell value not showing properly if decimal value is more than 2

Tags: excel, office365, office-js, office-addins

I am using **office.js** to render data in **Excel Office 365**. I using below method refer in [Range.numberFormat](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/excel/excel.range?view=excel-js-preview#excel-excel-range-numberformat-member)

```
Excel.run(context => {
    const sheetName = 'Sheet1';
    const rangeAddress = 'F5';
    const numberFormat = [['#,##0.000']];
    const values = [[5555555555715.747]];
    const range = context.workbook.worksheets
        .getItem(sheetName)
        .getRange(rangeAddress);
    range.numberFormat = numberFormat;
    range.values = values;
    range.load('text');
    context.sync();
});
```

But after rendering value its shows **5555555555715.75** instead of 5555555555715.747.
[image]

Comment: Excel can only hold 15 significant digits and your number has 16.  Excel will truncate and round to get to 15 significant digits.

Comment: Do you get the same picture when you enter the same number manually in Excel?

Comment: @EugeneAstafiev, If I type manually 5555555555715.747 -> 5555555555715.74. Last value is truncating.